# How do I stop google sheets from counting up numbers I input

Tags: google-sheets

41 pin plug
41 pin plug
41 pin plug
41 pin plug
41 pin plug
41 pin plug
41 pin plug

I use the drag method to repeat information in sheet that I am filling out but sheets keeps changing it like this

41 pin plug
42 pin plug
43 pin plug
44 pin plug
45 pin plug
46 pin plug
47 pin plug

I never want this to happen on this sheet at any row or column, how do I turn it off

Answer (score 5):

To disable the counting-up behavior:

- If you are using a Mac computer, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd> key as you drag.
- If you are using a Windows computer, hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key as you drag.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the `Ctrl` key as you drag to disable that behaviour.

Comment: When I hold Ctrl it opens a menu and does not let me drag the cells

Comment: Possibly a limitation of your browser. I've tested the above in the latest Google Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I am using a Mac Air, which is quite different from my pc.

Comment: Using a period after number does stop it ( 41. pin plug). I guess that is  how to  change integer to a statement.